# How to store each character of a user entered sentence separately in an array, within C

Tags: c, cs50

in C I was wondering how to store each character of a user entered sentence separately in an array.
Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: make an array. Step 2: read one character at a time with `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

```
size_t num_user_data = 0;
char** user_data = NULL;
char user_input[100] = {0} // don't use magic numbers in your code...;
while ( (gets(user_input)) && user_input[0] != '\n' ) {
    num_user_data += 1;
    user_data = realloc(user_data, sizeof(char*) * num_user_data);
    user_data[num_user_data-1] = strdup(user_input);
}

// You need to free user_data and user_data[i] somewhere...
```

`user_data[i][j]` will give you the character j of the i'th sentence entered.